# Adempiere - How to design/call CreateLinesFrom button in window

Tags: adempiere

I want to create CreateLineFrom form in my custom window/Table in WEBUI.

I have created CreateFrom field in my custom table and window level.

So is there any java code changes needed ?

Its already exists in Material Receipt standard window, now i want to do same thing in my custom window, so where i have to modify.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a process - there are lots of examples in the the org.compiere.process of the "base" module.
2. Create a new Process in the Application Dictionary and point it to your newly written process created in step 1.
3. Add a new column of reference type button to the table underlying the Window/Tab you'd like the button on and point this your new process by selecting the Process from the drop-down.
4. Finally add the new column created to the Windows/Tab were you need it to appear.